# Change of Variables for Integral over a Fractal

Tags: integration, measure-theory, substitution, fractal-analysis

We define the integral of a function $f(x,y)$ over a fractal $F$ to be,

$$(1) \quad \int_F f(x,y) \ d\mu(x,y)$$

Where $\mu$ is the normalized [Hausdorff measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure). Expressed another way, we have,

$$\int_F \ d\mu=\mu(F)=1$$

So, assuming $d\mu(W_n(s,t))=S_n(s,t) \cdot d\mu(s,t)$,

What is $S_n(s,t)$?

The Fractal we are considering for the integral is the attractor of the Dynamical System defined by,

$$F_{n+1}=W_1(F_n)\cup W_2(F_n)$$
$$W_1(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 0 \\ 1/2 & d_1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$$
$$W_2(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 0 \\ -1/2 & d_2 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 \\ 1/2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Where $F_0$ is the condensation set, and the transformations $W_1$ and $W_2$ are applied to each element of the set. The attractor $F$ satisfies,

$$(2) \quad F=W_1(F)\cup W_2(F)$$

The above is an IFS for anyone familiar with Michael Barnsley's work. So I'd like to integrate over this particular fractal in a specific fashion. I want the integral of $f(x,y)=y$ over $F$. Measures are additive so I can rewrite $(1)$ using $(2)$.

$$\int_F y \ d\mu(x,y)=\int_{W_1(F)} y \ d\mu(x,y)+\int_{W_2(F)} y \ d\mu(x,y)$$

I'd like to apply a change of variables to both integrals here. For the first one, I want

$$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=W_1(s,t)$$

For the second, I want,

$$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=W_2(s,t)$$

Doing this isn't the hardest thing, I literally substitute. Its the simplification that's getting me. So after substitution, I get that we have,

$$=\int_F \frac{1}{2} s+d_1 t \ d\mu \left(\frac{1}{2}s,\frac{1}{2}s+d_1 t\right)+\int_F -\frac{1}{2} s+d_2 t+\frac{1}{2} \ d\mu \left( \frac{1}{2}s+\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}s+d_2 t+\frac{1}{2} \right)$$

So, assuming $d\mu(W_n(s,t))=S_n(s,t) \cdot d\mu(s,t)$,

What is $S_n(s,t)$?

Can this be generalized to linear transformations?

I know that $d\mu(w \cdot s+a, w \cdot t+b)=w^d \cdot d\mu(s,t)$ where $d$ is the exponent in the Hausdorff measure, which is the fractal dimension.

For this particular case, I know that if $d_1=d_2=0$ then the integral is equal to $1/4$. This seems to lead to the conclusion that,

$$d\mu \left(\frac{1}{2}s,\frac{1}{2}s \right)=d\mu(s,s)=\frac{1}{2} d\mu(s,t)$$